# Solr 6 and Nutch 2.3.1 integration

Tags: solr, nutch

According to Nutch news the latest version of Nutch is 2.3.1 compatible with Solr 4.10.3 which is very old version of solr.

Can we integrate Solr 6 with Nutch 2.3.1. What will be the drawbacks if solr 6 will be integrated? Anybody tried this?

Comment: Nutch includes a schema.xml with all the fields it requires at $NUTCH_HOME\conf\schema.xml. The upgrade to solr 4.10.2 11 months ago is at https://github.com/apache/nutch/commit/a67cbc7d99c3b4172e690408f0abc54a098348bc

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but I just got Nutch 1.12 talking to Solr 6.3.0. The required schema/solrconfig changes should be the same for Nutch 2.x so here's what I did:

Download and extract both products into some directory, e.g. ~/mycrawler, then go into the solr directory and create a core for nutch:

```
solr-6.3.0/bin $ ./solr start
solr-6.3.0/bin $ ./solr create_core -c nutch -d basic_configs
solr-6.3.0/bin $ ./solr stop
```

This will create solr-6.3.0/server/solr/nutch where the schema etc. will be located. Now, we need to remove the new auto-managed schema definition and replace it with the nutch-supplied schema.xml:

```
solr-6.3.0/server/solr/nutch/conf $ rm managed-schema
solr-6.3.0/server/solr/nutch/conf $ cp ~/mycrawler/apache-nutch-1.12/conf/schema.xml .
```

Now edit schema.xml and remove all instances of  `enablePositionIncrements="true"` in all  `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" ...` definitions.

Also in `solr-6.3.0/server/solr/nutch/conf/solrconfig.xml`, comment these typeMapping blocks, so you get:

```
<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
    <!--
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
    <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
    <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
  </lst>
    -->
</processor>
```

Now start the server again:

```
solr-6.3.0/bin $ ./solr start
```

If you go to the admin gui, it should show the core as started with no further schema issues.

Now the crawl script can be run and will successfully write into our bleeding edge Solr (this is probably slightly different for Nutch 2):

```
./crawl -i \
    -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch \ 
    ~/mycrawler/nutch_work/seed \
    ~/mycrawler/nutch_work/crawl  \
    1
```

Comment: I am getting the following exception in the browser UI. Any Idea?

    `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core nutch: Can't load schema /server/solr/nutch/conf/schema.xml: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilterFactory'`

Comment: sounds like you forgot to remove one of the  enablePositionIncrements="true" in a StopFilterFactory definition... there's a bunch of them all over schema.xml

Comment: Exactly... Solved.

Comment: it seems you miss some steps, e.g. creating the seed file?

Comment: Nutch comes with a separate schema file for Solr 4.X Copy the schema-solr4.xml file  for Solr 4+ and renamed managed schema file to schema.xml. Also add
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/> to solarconfig.xml in the conf folder