# Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "pfloat": Error loading class 'solr.FloatField'

Tags: solr, nutch

```
nutch:arg.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: 
Could not load conf for core nutch: Can't load schema D:\solr-6.5.0\server\solr\nutch\conf\schema.xml: 
    Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "pfloat": Error loading class 'solr.FloatField'
```

I'm finding this error, can anyone help to fix it?

Comment: Could you please provide more information?

Comment: Followed this procedure... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525848/solr-6-and-nutch-2-3-1-integration/44889940..  and I can't able to figure out the exact mistake done by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FloatField was removed in Solr 5. Use `solr.TrieFloatField` instead.